# Monty Hall game in R with base functions

Tags: r, probability

Just for fun and to train R, I tried to proof the Monty Hall Game rule (changing your choice after one gate opened gives you more probability to win), I made this reproducible code (The explanation of every step is within the code):

```
## First I set the seed

set.seed(4)

## Then I modelize the presence of the prize as a random variable between gates 1,2,3


randomgates <- ceiling(runif(10000, min = 0, max = 3))

## so do I with the random choice.

randomchoice <- ceiling(runif(10000, min = 0, max = 3))

## As the opening of a gate is dependent from the gate you chose (the gate you chose cannot be opened)
## I modelize the opening of the gate as a variable which cannot be equal to the choice.

options <- c(1:3)

randomopen <- rep(1,10000)

for (i in 1:length(randomgates)) {
  realoptions <- options[options != randomchoice[i]]
  randomopen[i] <- realoptions[ceiling(runif(1,min = 0, max = 2))]
}

##Just to make data more easy to handle, I make a dataset

dataset <- cbind(randomgates, randomchoice, randomopen)

## Then I creat a dataset which only keeps the realization of the games in which we carry on (
## the opened gate wasn't the one with the price within)

steptwo <- dataset[randomopen != randomgates,]

## The next step is just to check if the probability of carry on is 2/3, which indeed is

carryon <- randomopen != randomgates

sum(carryon)/length(randomgates) 

## I format the dataset as a data frame

steptwo <- as.data.frame(steptwo)

## Now we check what happens if we hold our initial choice when game carries on

prizesholding <- steptwo$randomgates == steptwo$randomchoice

sum(prizesholding)

## creating a vector of changing option, dependant on the opened gate, in the dataset that
## keeps only the cases in which we carried on playing (the opened gate wasn't the one with the prize)

switchedchoice <- rep(1,length(steptwo$randomgates)) 

for (i in 1:length(steptwo$randomgates)) {
  choice <- options[options != steptwo$randomchoice[i]]
  switchedchoice[i] <- choice[ceiling(runif(1,min = 0, max = 2))]
}

## Now we check how many times you guess the prize gate when you switch your initial choice

prizesswitching <- steptwo$randomgates == switchedchoice

sum(prizesswitching)/length(steptwo$randomgates)
```

When I check the probability without changing my initial choice in the cases in which the game carried on (the gate opening didn't match the one with the prize) I obtain what I exepected (close 1/3 of probability of winning the prize), which refers to the following instruction:

```
carryon <- randomopen != randomgates

sum(carryon)/length(randomgates)
```

My problem arises when I check the probability of winning the prize after changing my choice (conditionate, obviously to not having opened the door which holds the prize), instead of getting 1/2 as Monty Hall states, I get 1/4, it refers to the following instruction:

```
prizesswitching <- steptwo$randomgates == switchedchoice

sum(prizesswitching)/length(steptwo$randomgates)
```

I know that I am doing something bad because it is already more than proofed that Monty Hall holds, but I am not able to detect the flaw. Does anyone know what it is?

If you don't know what Monty Hall problem is, you can find easy-to-read information at wikipedia:

[Monty Hall Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem)

Edit: As @Dason pointed out, one of the problem was I was introducing some kind of randomness in the changing of the initial choice, which doesn't makes sense as there is only one option left.

Other problem was that I was not approaching the problem under the assumption of Monty Hall knowing where the prize is. I changed my code from the initial to this, and the problem is solved:

```
# Prepare each variable for 10000 experiments

## First I set the seed

set.seed(4)

## Then I modelize the presence of the prize as a random variable between gates 1,2,3


randomgates <- ceiling(runif(10000, min = 0, max = 3))

## so do I with the random choice.

randomchoice <- ceiling(runif(10000, min = 0, max = 3))

## As the opening of a gate is dependent from the gate you chose (the gate you chose cannot be opened
##, neither the one with the prize does), I modelize the opening of the gate as a variable which cannot be equal to the choice.

options <- c(1:3)

randomopen <- rep(1,10000)

for (i in 1:length(randomgates)) {
  randomopen[i] <- options[options != randomchoice[i] & options != randomgates[i]]
}

##Just to make data more easy to handle, I make a dataset

dataset <- cbind(randomgates, randomchoice, randomopen)

## I format the dataset as a data frame

steptwo <- as.data.frame(dataset)

## Now we check what happens if we hold our initial choice when game carries on

steptwo$prizesholding <- steptwo$randomgates == steptwo$randomchoice

with(steptwo, sum(prizesholding))

## creating a vector of changing option, dependant on the opened gate, in the dataset that
## keeps only the cases in which we carried on playing (the opened gate wasn't the one with the prize)

steptwo$switchedchoice <- rep(1,length(steptwo$randomgates)) 

for (i in 1:length(steptwo$randomgates)) {
  steptwo$switchedchoice[i] <- options[options != steptwo$randomchoice[i] & options != steptwo$randomopen[i]]
}

## Now we check how many times you guess the prize gate when you switch your initial choice

steptwo$prizesswitching <- steptwo$randomgates == steptwo$switchedchoice

with(steptwo, sum(prizesswitching)/length(randomgates))
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have any randomness being introduced when the contestant decides to switch.  One door is already open, they already have chosen a door, so there is only one door left.

Comment: @Dason yep, I think you spotted the problem, but I don't know how to code a variable which is not equal either to the gate initially chosen nor to the gate opened_ I tried something like this `for (i in 1:length(steptwo$randomgates)) {
  choice <- options[options != steptwo$randomchoice[i] | steptwo$randomgates]

  switchedchoice[i] <- choice
}`

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
n_iter <- 10000

set.seed(4)

doors <- 1:3
prizes <- sample.int(n = 3, size = n_iter, replace = TRUE)
your_pick <- sample.int(n = 3, size = n_iter, replace = TRUE)
open_door <- rep(0, n_iter)
switched_door <- rep(0, n_iter)

for (i in 1:n_iter) {
  remaining_choices <- setdiff(doors, c(your_pick[i], prizes[i]))

  if (length(remaining_choices) > 1) {
    open_door[i] <- sample(remaining_choices, size = 1)
  } else {
    open_door[i] <- remaining_choices
  }

  switched_door[i] <- setdiff(doors, c(your_pick[i], open_door[i]))
}

> mean(your_pick == prizes)
[1] 0.3305
> mean(switched_door == prizes)
[1] 0.6695
```

The `sample.int` and `sample` base functions help simplify things a bit. The `remaining_choices` item contains the possible doors that can be opened by the game show host, which has a length of 1 or 2 depending on your original choice. If the length is 2, we sample from that vector, and if it's 1, that door is automatically opened.

Answer (score 3):

Each round, there is a prize_door and a chosen_door. Monty Hall will open a door that is not a prize_door or chosen_door (setdiff between 1:3 and the vector (prize_door, chosen_door), with a random choice between the two if the setdiff is two elements). Then the switch door is the door not chosen or opened.

```
n <- 1e4
set.seed(2020)
df <- 
  data.frame(
    prize_door = sample(1:3, n, replace = TRUE),
    chosen_door = sample(1:3, n, replace = TRUE))

df$opened_door <- 
  mapply(function(x, y){
    available <- setdiff(1:3, c(x, y))
    available[sample(length(available), 1)]
  }, df$prize_door, df$chosen_door)

df$switch_door <- 
  mapply(function(x, y) setdiff(1:3, c(x, y)),
  df$chosen_door, df$opened_door)



with(df, mean(prize_door == chosen_door))
# [1] 0.3358
with(df, mean(prize_door == switch_door))
# [1] 0.6642
```

Plot of probabilities as n increases

```
probs <- 
  data.frame(
    chosen_p = with(df, cumsum(prize_door == chosen_door))/(1:n),
    switch_p = with(df, cumsum(prize_door == switch_door))/(1:n))

plot(probs$switch_p, type = 'l', ylim = c(0, 1))
lines(probs$chosen_p, col = 'red')
abline(h = 1/3)
abline(h = 2/3)
```

[image]